# is it possible to get the depth information with two images caught in a scene?

Tags: image-processing, 3d, 2d, computer-vision

I have two images photographed in a same scene. the two image is photographed by two camera lined horizontally with a short distance to each other but shoot to the same focus. here is the question: Is it possible to calculate the distance of the camera to the image with the information of the two images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stereo vision allows discovering the distance of the object to the camera, if you manage to compute a correct disparity map (which is one of the main challenges of computer stereo vision), and the objects are close enough. The focus of the cameras is not relevant, as long as it is good enough to calculate the disparity map.

Comment: The focus is actually important, since the sharpness of your images is closely related to the quality of the matches you will be able to make between your two frames.